# ifstream get the wrong string inside a file

Tags: c++, fstream

The code is as follow :

#### The Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int id;
    char name[50];
    ifstream myfile("savingaccount.txt");  //open the file
    myfile >> id;

    myfile.getline(name , 255 , '\n');   //read name **second line of the file
    cout << id ;
    cout << "\n" << name << endl; //Error part : only print out partial name 
    return 0;
}
```

#### **The File Content:**

1800567
Ho Rui Jang
21
Female
Malaysian
012-4998192
20 , Lorong 13 , Taman Patani Janam
Melaka
Sungai Dulong

#### **The Problem :**

1.)I expect the getline will read the name into the char array name and then I can print out the name , the thing is instead of getting the full name , I only get partial of the name , why this happen?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it the exactly same code? Also, what does it print? Post the output also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `myfile >> id` does not consume the newline (`\n`) at the end of the first line. Thus, when you call `getline` it will read from the end of the ID until the end of that line, and you will get an empty string. If you call again `getline` it will actually return the name.

```
std::string name; // By using std::getline() you can use std::string
                  // instead of a char array

myfile >> id;
std::getline(myfile, name); // this one will be empty
std::getline(myfile, name); // this one will contain the name
```

My advise would be to just use `std::getline` for all the lines and if a line contains a number you can just convert it using [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (if your compiler supports C++11) or [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html).

Comment: In addition, to parse more complex lines, pass the string to the constructor for an `std::ostringstream`, and run extractors as appropriate.

Comment: @PeteBecker Indeed. Using regular expressions can be also handy depending on the input format.

Comment: I try to cout myfile.tellg() "myfile >> id;" and the value i get is 16 , why is it so?I thought the first line 1800567 should have 7 digits and after reading it with "myfile >> id" the stream pointer should be placed at the position before name which is 7 or 8 but why 16?

Comment: @caramel23 I am not 100% sure, but it can be related to the encoding that your are using. For instance, if you are using UTF-16 each character will occupy two bytes. And 16 = 8 x 2.